# Charts.js 2.5 does not display in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, charts

I am trying to get some charts displaying in my main view with Django version 1.11. I did some test to check if the JS libraries were working correctly by typing some alert("Success") but the alerts did not appear in my browser (Chrome version 58).

**Main HTML file:**

```
{% extends "personal_website/header.html"%}
<script>
{% block jquery %}
var endpoint = 'statistics' 

//Code to display the charts
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
{% endblock %}
// end of code to display charts
</script>

{% block content %}

<div class ='row'>
    <div class="col-sm-12" url-endpoint='{% url "statistics" %}'>
    <h1>Statistics for week 21</h1>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="600"></canvas>     
</div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**header.html**

```
<head>
    <title>Statistics</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'personal_website/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body class="body" style="background-color:#f6f6f6">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="min-height:95%; ">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-10">
              <h3>Statistics</h3>
           </div>
         </div><hr>
         <div class="well bs-sidebar" id="sidebar">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
               <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
               <li><a href='/statistics/'>Statistics</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
    </div>            
<footer>
    <!-- no content for the moment-->   
</footer>   
</body>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Just to add a few more observations, I am able to see see the main html with the H3 tags rendered and if I inspect the code with the dev chrome tools, I am able to see the canvas but no chart is displayed, meaning that something could be wrong with the JS libraries. Any idea, suggestion or new proposal to spot this error is welcome.

Comment: You are trying to override a block called `jquery` in your main HTML but there is no such block in your base template (`header.html`). Also consider moving the `script` tags before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: So, in this case I should add a {% block jquery %} in my header.html file ? I moved the script tags before de closing </body> tag but I ve got not success.

Comment: I did some modifications and you were right @Selcuk! I had to put the jQuery content inside of my header.html file.

Comment: No worries. You can accept your own answer to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some corrections and suggestion made by @Selcuk I ended up with the following results that were necessary to see the displayed graphs.

**Main HTML not modified**

```
{% extends "personal_website/header.html"%}
<script>
{% block jquery %}
var endpoint = 'statistics' 

//Code to display the charts
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
},
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }]
    }
}
});
{% endblock %}
// end of code to display charts
</script>

{% block content %}

<div class ='row'>
<div class="col-sm-12" url-endpoint='{% url "statistics" %}'>
<h1>Statistics for week 21</h1>
<canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="600"></canvas>     
</div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**Header html file modified**

```
<head>
<title>Statistics</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'personal_website/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type = "text/css"/> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body class="body" style="background-color:#f6f6f6">
<div class="container-fluid" style="min-height:95%; ">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-10">
          <h3>Statistics</h3>
       </div>
     </div><hr>
     <div class="well bs-sidebar" id="sidebar">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
           <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
           <li><a href='/statistics/'>Statistics</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
    </div>            
<footer>
    <!-- no content for the moment-->   
</footer>
<script 
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script 
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js">
</script>   
<script>
    {% block jquery %}
    {% endblock %}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```